# Why isn't __bases__ accessible in the class body?

Tags: python, class, inheritance

Class objects have a `__bases__` (and a `__base__`) attribute:

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     pass
... 
>>> Foo.__bases__
(<class 'object'>,)
```

Sadly, these attributes aren't accessible in the class body, which would be very convenient for accessing parent class attributes without having to hard-code the name:

```
class Foo:
    cls_attr = 3

class Bar(Foo):
    cls_attr = __base__.cls_attr + 2
    # throws NameError: name '__base__' is not defined
```

Is there a reason why `__bases__` and `__base__` can't be accessed in the class body?

(To be clear, I'm asking if this is a conscious design decision. I'm not asking about the implementation; I know that `__bases__` is a descriptor in `type` and that this descriptor can't be accessed until a class object has been created. I want to know why python doesn't create `__bases__` as a local variable in the class body.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I want to know why python doesn't create `__bases__` as a local variable in the class body

As you know, `class` is mostly a shortcut for `type.__new__()` - when the runtime hits a `class` statements, it executes all statements at the top-level of the `class` body, collects all resulting bindings in a dedicated namespace dict, calls `type()` with the concrete metaclass, the class name, the base classes and the namespace dict, and binds the resulting class object to the class name in the enclosing scope (usually but not necessarily the module's top-level namespace).

The important point here is that it's the metaclass responsabilty to build the class object, and to allow for class object creation customisations, the metaclass must be free to do whatever it wants with its arguments. Most often a custom metaclass will mainly work on the `attrs` dict, but it must also be able to mess with the `bases` argument. Now since the metaclass is only invoked AFTER the class body statements have been executed, there's no way the runtime can reliably expose the `bases` in the class body scope since those bases could be modified afterward by the metaclass.

There are also some more philosophical considerations here, notably wrt/ explicit vs implicit, and as shx2 mentions, Python designers try to avoid magic variables popping out of the blue. There are indeed a couple implementation variables (`__module__` and, in py3, `__qualname__`) that are "automagically" defined in the class body namespace, but those are just names, mostly intended as  additional debugging / inspection informations for developers)  and have absolutely no impact on the class object creation nor on its properties, behaviour and whatnots.

As always with Python, you have to consider the whole context (the execution model, the object model, how the different parts work together etc) to really understand the design choices. Whether you agree with the whole design and philosophy is another debate (and one that doesn't belong here), but you can be sure that yes, those choices **are** "conscious design decisions".

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your "`__bases__` has a huge impact on the class" argument. So what if it does? How is that a reason to not make it available in the class body? How does it make hard-coding the parent class better than referring to it by the name `__base__`?

Comment: If I understand correctly, your explanation basically boils down to "The metaclass could change the base classes and then people might be confused what `__base__` and `__bases__` really refer to"?

Comment: @Aran-Fey yes, that's the point indeed - specially when considering that if the "original" value of `__bases__` was exposed that way, using `__bases__[0]` instead of the hardcoded class name doesn't bring that much in terms of readability and maintainability (it would make the code a litte bit DRYer but that's about the only thing you'd get - at least the only thing I can think of).

Comment: NB: to make things clear, I'm not saying that it's the best possible design nor that you have to agree with this choice - just that it makes sense in the context of Python's execution model and is consistant with Python's philosophy.

Comment: Fair enough. I don't think it's a good argument (and more importantly, I'm really not convinced that any of the devs gave it any serious thought), but you have my upvote.

Comment: @Aran-Fey things might have changed quite a bit in Python's ecosystem recently with the BDFL leaving, but having watched the language evolutions since the 1.5.2 days, I can tell you that the core team is historically known for giving very serious thought to design choices.

Answer (score 2):

I am not answering as to why it was decided to be implemented the way it was, I'm answering why it wasn't implemented as a "local variable in the class body":

Simply because nothing in python is a local variable magically defined in the class body.  Python doesn't like names magically appearing out of nowhere.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is it... Things like `__module__` and `__qualname__` do magically appear as local variables in the class body, after all.

Answer (score 0):

It's because it's simply is not yet created.

Consider the following:

```
>>> class baselessmeta(type):
...     def __new__(metaclass, class_name, bases, classdict):
...         return type.__new__(
...             metaclass,
...             class_name,
...             (), # I can just ignore all the base
...             {}
...         )
...
>>> class Baseless(int, metaclass=baselessmeta):
...     # imaginary print(__bases__, __base__)
...     ...
...
>>> Baseless.__bases__
(<class 'object'>,)
>>> Baseless.__base__
<class 'object'>
>>>
```

What should the imaginary print result in? 
Every python class is created via the `type` metaclass one way or another.
You have the `int` argument for the `type()` in `bases` argument, yet you do not know what is the return value is going to be. You may use that directly as a base in your metaclass, or you may return another base with your LOC.

Just realized your `to be clear` part and now my answer is useless haha. Oh welp.

Comment: Well, it's certainly true that the class doesn't exist yet, but python could just set `__base__` to whatever you wrote in parentheses after the class name (`(int,)` in your example). Python *does* create `__module__` and `__qualname__` as local variables, and both of those can be changed or ignored by the metaclass, too, just like `__bases__`. Anyway, I'd expect the imaginary print to output `(int,) int` - it really can't output anything else, because, like you said, the metaclass's `__new__` hasn't been executed yet at that point.

Comment: @Aran-Fey `__module__` and `__qualname__` are only textual informations intended as debugging help - they have zero impact on the properties (in the most general definition) of the final `class` object. `bases` OTHO has a __huge__ impact on the resulting class...